# C and the strcmp() function

Tags: c, strcmp

The point of this program is to rename the file extensions of all the files in the current directory.

Here is some of the code:

```
 while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            char *ext = strrchr(dir->d_name, '.');

            if (!strcmp(ext + 1, argv[1])) // :)
            {
                char name[strlen(dir->d_name)];
                strcpy(name, dir->d_name);

                name[strlen(name) - strlen(ext) + 1] = '\0'; // :)
                strcat(name, argv[2]);

                if (rename(dir->d_name, name) != 0)
                {
                    syslog(LOG_ALERT, "Could not rename file %s!", dir->d_name);
                }
            }
        }
```

I did this a while back, but I can't understand why the strcmp if-statement works. It looks insane to me.

However, calling it with the arguments "JPG jpg" does indeed rename the JPG-files.

What dark art is at work here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If `ext` points to the `'.'` in the file name then `ext + 1` points to the char after the `'.'`. That is, the first letter of the extension (assuming only 1 `'.'` in the file name).

Comment: Your `name` array isn't big enough to hold the filename btw. Also need to account for the case of the new extension being longer than the current one.

Comment: `char name[strlen(dir->d_name)];` is bad. You need one more element for terminating null-character. You may need more based on values of `ext` and `argv[2]`.

Comment: But the if is "if (!...)", which is what confuses me. And weirdly, strcat() works even if you would rename from ".c" to ".java" for instance.

Comment: `strcmp()` returns `0` when the strings are equal. So `if(!strcmp(...))` will be true when the strings are equal.

Comment: There should be some check if a `'.'` was found at all in the filename. Otherwise a `NULL` pointer will be used.

Comment: The best way to understand this program is to run it line by line in a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471) while monitoring the values of all variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strcmp()` returns an integer value, and an integer is implicitly converted to a Boolean when applied as an operand to a Boolean operator such as `!`.

The conversion is zero to `false`, non-zero to `true`.

So `!strcmp(ext + 1, argv[1])` is semantically identical to `strcmp(ext + 1, argv[1]) == 0`.

Not insane, and a very common idiom amongst those who favour terseness over clarity.  You also commonly see it applied to pointers to test for `NULL`.  I would advise against it in general.

Comment: "*favour type agreement over implicit conversion*" -- perhaps you could rephrase this in terms of some concept other than data type, as there are no such conversions as you claim in the OP's code.  At least not according to C semantics.  `!` operates directly on integers (among other type categories), no conversion required, and its result has type `int`, not `_Bool` (nor `Boolean`, which is not a built-in C data type).  And C conditional expressions operate directly on integers (among other types), too, so there's no after-the-fact conversion, either.

Comment: @JohnBollinger your point is noted.  I long ago stopped using C regularly for C++.  It may be simpler to just remove the statement to avoid unnecessary discussion of a minor semantic point. I think my advice would be the same nonetheless, it is _conceptually_ and semantically a Boolean expression having only two possible values  regardless of the containing type.  Note I used the _term_ "Boolean" not `Boolean` so as not to imply an actual _type_.

Answer (score 3):

Let's disassemble it.

```c
if(!strcmp(ext + 1, argv[1]))
```

1. ext + 1 is a pointer pointing to the first char of the extension, and argv[1] is pointing to the start of your command line input.
2. strcmp will compare the two strings, and if it finds that they are the same, it will return 0.
3. if x equals to 0, then the logical not `!x == 1`; otherwise `!x == 0`.
4. in the if-statement, we will run into the embrace **IF** the condition is **NOT** 0.

So this statement will do the rename when the extension of the file matches your command line input.

Which part of this statement confused you?